# Does (or has in the past) an adaptor existed to mount a disc rotor to a Shimano Rollerbrake type hub?

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, internally-geared-hub, nexus, roller-brake

I have acquired a Nexus 8speed rear hub. It’s a good one and I’d love to use it. However, it has been set up to use rim brakes and under the plastic cover is the interface to mount a rollerbrake. Does anyone know if an adaptor has ever existed to fit a standard disc rotor to this interface?

It should be inferred that if it won’t work with disc, this hub is of little use to me.

It may sound like a preposterous question, but other internally geared hub makers use an exchangeable format on a similarish interface to allow use of their hub with different braking systems.

Thankyou for your input.